# MySQL Import: PhpMyAdmin won't let me access 'information_schema'

Tags: mysql, database, information-schema

A while ago I backed up (exported) my mysql database into an .sql file. When I did this, it exported the information_schema from that database as well- even though I didn't really want it to. (Unless I'd need information_schema for some reason.) Now, here I am on a seperate phpmyadmin account, trying to import my .sql file, but in doing so I get:

## 1044 - Access denied for user 'sql595249'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

There's a lot of code in this .sql file that has to do with information_schema, I tried just removing the first few lines where the export says to create it, but that doesn't work because it's still tyring to insert a bunch of tables and what not. I'm not sure how I'd remove every line of code that modifies it without struggling for hours on end.

Also, I'm on a company's hosted phpmyadmin- meaning the server isn't ran on my own computer. I can't install any special type of software to phpmyadmin or mysql.

Comment: Can you add some relevant parts of the dump to the question? That way we'll see whether they can be safely filtered out of the dump, or whether you need elevated privileges.

Comment: information_schema is read only, it contains metadata of all database objects on a mysql instance. When you create, modify, or drop any database objects, mysql automatically updates information_schema. So, no need to dump it and you cannot directly restore it.

Comment: I don't know how to open the bash command line. Can someone walk me through getting there on phpmyadmin? I'm not sure if I'm even able to access it because i'm not hosting the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dump dumped out the information_schema database. You can possibly fix it like this:

On the bash command line:

```
sed -i s/information_schema/information_schema_foo/i dump.sql
```

Then load the updated dump. You will have a new database information_schema_foo. You can drop it.

This works assuming you have no real data that have the substring information_schema. You can verify this by running

```
grep -i information_schema dump.sql
```

Comment: Run this as a.. query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: No, both are Bash commands to be run from the terminal. If you are on Windows, get Cygwin or you can use a text editor search/replace function. If you are on a Mac or Linux you have a native terminal. dump.sql is the name of your dump file.

Comment: Mysqldump does not output objects at random, they are grouped together. Just delete the information_schema related create tables and inserts manually using a text editor, no need to run any script.

Comment: I'm using a hosting company's mysql server- all I have is access to their phpmyadmin- and the server isn't running on my own computer. Sasha, will your method still work regardless of this?

Comment: Also- shadow, when I tried that earlier I had a hard time telling where it began.

Comment: I just manually edited out the information_schema part with a text editor.